# Entity Framework 6 order by using reflection

Tags: entity-framework-6, system.reflection

I’m trying to populate a one to many relation via c# reflection.
What I’m trying to achieve is the following EF query

```
_db.Entry(item).Collection(p => p.Valori).Query().OrderBy(o=>o.Ordinamento).Load();
```

My requirement is to create the query automatically with an annotation of my own

```
    [EagerLoad("Ordinamento")]
    [InverseProperty("Attributo")]
    public virtual ICollection<AttributoValore> Valori { get; set; }
```

Until the order by statement all works fine

```
    _db.Entry(entity).Collection(propertyInfo.Name).Load();
```

where entity is the object that contains the collection I want to populate and propertyInfo.Name == “Valori”.

I can’t find the right syntax to create the lamda expression this code

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
Expression<Func<object, K>> expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, K>>(Expression.Property(pe, el.ordinamento), pe);


_db.Entry(entity)
    .Collection<Object>(propertyInfo.Name)
    .Query()
    .OrderBy(expr)
    .Load();
```

Generates an exception:
System.ArgumentException: 'ParameterExpression of type 'Jerp.AttributoValore' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object''
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody has the same requirement. It is possible to implement fluent api EF6 syntax via repleflection. The way I found is a bit complicated:

```
                    Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                    //_db.Entry(entity)
                    var entry = _db.Entry(entity);

                    //    .Collection<AttributoValore>(propertyInfo.Name)
                    MethodInfo collectionMethod = typeof(EntityEntry<T>)
                                .GetMethod("Collection", new Type[] { typeof(String) })
                                .MakeGenericMethod(type);
                    var query= collectionMethod.Invoke(entry, new object[] { propertyInfo.Name });

                    //    .Query()
                    MethodInfo queryMethod = typeof(CollectionEntry<,>)
                                .MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(T), type })
                                .GetMethod("Query", new Type[] { });
                    var orderBy = queryMethod.Invoke(query, null);

                    //    .OrderByRules(new List<OrderRule> { new OrderRule(el.ordinamento, false) })
                    MethodInfo orderByMethod = typeof(MyLINQExtensions)
                            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault()
                            .MakeGenericMethod(type);
                    var load = orderByMethod.Invoke(orderBy, new object[] { orderBy, new List<OrderRule> { new OrderRule(el.ordinamento, false) } });

                    //    .Load();
                    MethodInfo loadMethod = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
                            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name == "Load").FirstOrDefault()
                            .MakeGenericMethod(type);
                    loadMethod.Invoke(load, new object[] { load });
```